2x4, for ATX PCIe socket same polarity as VGA 6+2 socket?
I have an FPGA that I would like to connect using PCIe to a host computer. This FPGA board, the VCK190, has a power socket for PCIe.
I have a PCIe power cable with the typical VGA 6+2 interface. However, according to its specifications, the board has a "2x4, ATX PCIe power connector."
I have attached photos of the male and female plugs:


Now, the question to you, which an hour of googling could not solve: Do these plugs have the same polarity despite the top-left hole in the female plug being a square and the corresponding plug being rounded?
As a little child, you usually learn not to put the wrong shapes in the wrong hole, but a famous video tells me that it is wrong.
P.S. The cable should go from the power-supply to the FPGA

Does this cable go to a power supply?

Does this answer your question? What happens after plugging in 6+2 pin power cable into 2x4pin for CPU into motherboard?
